# How to set up this duplication function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplication

This is what I need to make work in JavaScript:
￼

```
[1,2,3,4,5].duplicate(); // [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Best practices? Ideas?

Comment: What are you asking for? How to write the content of `duplicate` or how to make it so that you can custom define a method `duplicate` on an array object?

Comment: @FrankV The second of those

Answer (score 3):

Use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) on the same `array`. It'll duplicate the elements of the array.

> The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

```
// Define method on prototype so that it can be directly called on array
Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {
    return this.concat(this);
};
```